# Multivariate polynomials with prescribed zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_k\subsetneq\Bbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the set of degree $k$ multivariate real polynomials. Pick a subset $S$ of $\{-1,+1\}^n$ of size $|S|<\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}$. We seek a polynomial $$q(z)\in P_k:q(z)=0,\mbox{ }\forall z\in S$$

Since number of relevant coefficients of any $q\in P_k$ is atmost $\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}$, we get a system of homogeneous equations with $|S|$ equations and one can get a $$q(z)\in P_k:q(z)=0,\mbox{ }\forall z\in S$$

My question: is there be a $z\in\{-1,+1\}^n\backslash S:q(z)=0$ for $$\mbox{case }1:\mbox{  any such }S$$ $$\mbox{case }2:\mbox{ some }S?$$

How about if $|S|=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}$?